Difference between "Copying -> Move To" and dragging an item to move it when the source item is in a bucket
In my SXA 10.3.1 site, I want to move a bucketable item out of a bucket and into an unbucketable folder that is a direct child of the parent bucket item. When doing so, I get different results based on how I perform the "move" operation.
Consider the following example content tree, where  is a bucket,  is a bucketable page item, and ️ is an unbucketable folder item:
- Blogs    (Is Bucket = true)
  - 2023  
    - 01  
      - Blog post 1 
    - 02   
      - Blog post 2 
  - 2024  
    - 01  
      - Blog post 3 
    - 02  
      - Blog post 4 
  - Archive ️
    - 2022  ️
      - Blog post 5 
    - 2023  ️

The year and month  items are created via a custom bucket path which is based on a Date field of the  items. This occurs on the item:saved event.
Problem
When I attempt to move one of the  items into a ️, I get different results depending on how the move operation is performed. This issue has been observed in multiple environments by multiple users. This issue only happens when working with items that are in buckets.
1. Right clicking an item and selecting "Copying" --> "Move To"

Right click one of the  items. Select "Copying" --> "Move To"
Select 2022 ️ as the destination.
Prompt appears: "This operation may take a long time to complete. Are you sure you want to continue?"
Press "OK". Nothing happens. The item does not move. The item:saved event handler does not get called.
Try again, this time picking Archive ️ as the destination. The same prompt appears. Press "OK". In the content tree, the Archive ️ item actually automatically becomes expanded, revealing its children (unlike before when 2022 ️ was selected as the destination), but ultimately the item does not move. There are no errors or warnings in the Sitecore logs.

2. Moving the item via drag and drop

Drag  item to 2022 ️
Prompt appears: "Are you sure you want to move ?
Press "OK"
Prompt appears: "This operation may take a long time to complete. Are you sure you want to continue?"
Press "OK"
The custom item:saved event handler is called.
The item moves successfully.

What are the relevant differences between these two methods of moving an item, and why might the difference(s) be causing issues in this case?
Additional Analysis
ShowConfig.aspx does indicate that there is a difference between the two methods of moving items:
<uiDragItemTo>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Pipelines.DragItemTo,Sitecore.Kernel" method="CheckPermissions" mode="on"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Pipelines.DragItemTo,Sitecore.Kernel" method="Confirm" mode="on"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Pipelines.DragItemTo,Sitecore.Kernel" method="CheckLanguage" mode="on"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Pipelines.DragItemTo,Sitecore.Kernel" method="CheckLinks" mode="on"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.UI.ItemDrag, Sitecore.Buckets" method="Execute" mode="on" patch:source="Sitecore.Buckets.config"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Pipelines.DragItemTo,Sitecore.Kernel" method="Execute" mode="on"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Pipelines.DragItemTo,Sitecore.Kernel" method="RepairLinks" mode="on"/>
</uiDragItemTo>

<uiMoveItems>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Pipelines.MoveItems,Sitecore.Kernel" method="CheckPermissions" mode="on"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.Processors.UiMoveItems.MoveItems, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite" method="ShowDialog" mode="on" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.config"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Pipelines.MoveItems,Sitecore.Kernel" method="CheckLinks" mode="on"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.UI.ItemMove, Sitecore.Buckets" method="Execute" mode="on" patch:source="Sitecore.Buckets.config"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Pipelines.MoveItems,Sitecore.Kernel" method="RepairLinks" mode="on"/>
</uiMoveItems>


Works for me on both 10.1.2 and 10.3.0. I don't have 10.3.1 spinned up now, so cannot check on your version. Don't you have some custom code (like event handlers for item:saving  or item:bucketing:dragInto)? Do you see Log.Audit((object) this, "Move item: {0} to {1}" message in your logs?

@MarekMusielak I see 17:28:24 INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\Admin): Drag item: master:/sitecore/content/... in the logs when dragging. Nothing appears in the logs when using Copying -> Move To. The only somewhat relevant custom event handler in play is item:saved, which, if all conditions are met, performs a BucketManager.Sync(). Else it does nothing. Either way, it does not appear to be the source of the issue.

I've just tried this on a vanilla Sitecore 10.3.1 instance and couldn't reproduce it either. Please can you share how your pipelines <uiDragItemTo> and <uiMoveItems> look in showconfig.aspx? I wonder if there is a config patch that causes this behaviour.

@AnnaGevel I have added more info to the question. SXA multisite is a factor here.

@MarcelGruber that's interesting, my 10.3.1 has SXA installed and pipelines match yours, but I previously tested it on a non-SXA site. I've just tried on an SXA site and got the same result - items are moved just fine.  The only difference is that I don't get the prompt "This operation may take a long time to complete. Are you sure you want to continue?". Do you see any errors in the browser console when using "Copying" --> "Move To"?
